# How to wait for the HTTP request to get completed in java

Tags: java, rest, file, http

I am writing Java code where i am downloading the file from a server and i have to copy the file in my local system when the file download is complete.

I am using the below code:-

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        OkHttpClient client = builder.readTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        Request downloadRequest = new Request.Builder().url(url + fileName).addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .addHeader("Authorization", token).build();
        try {
            Response downloadResponse = client.newCall(downloadRequest).execute();
            System.out.println(downloadResponse.message());
            System.out.println("got response from blob " + downloadResponse.isSuccessful() + " " + fileName);
            return downloadResponse;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
```

}

But the request is made asynchronously and before the request is completed then response is returned which is incomplete. Can anyone please help me how can i make a request and wait till the response is completed.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The execute() is already a blocking call. It should wait until the download is complete. What is the output of downloadResponse.isSuccessful() or response status code?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're returning the response object (not the response body content).

try something like:

```
return downloadedResponse.body().string()
```

My experience with HttpClient is such that the headers return first.  The content doesn't necessarily come across the wire unless/until you consume it.

Answer (score 0):

To make a synchronous GET request we need to build a Request object based on a URL and make a Call. After its execution we get back an instance of Response:

```
@Test
public void whenGetRequest_thenCorrect() throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(BASE_URL + "/date")
      .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    Response response = call.execute();

    assertThat(response.code(), equalTo(200));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already using synchronous method calling.

`client.newCall(downloadRequest).execute();`

This is a synchronous way of requesting URL. If you want to do the aysynchronous call you need to use enqueue method of Call class.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) 
          throws IOException {
            // ...
        }

        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            fail();
        }
    });
```

I think problem is somewhere else. Kindly give more details why you are suspecting the current one as an asynchronous call so that we can do RCA.